# How to install R packages via proxy [user + password]

Tags: r

I need authentication to use internet, say these are my variables:

1. Proxy : 1ncproxy1
2. Port : 80
3. Loggin : MyLoGiN
4. Pass : MyPaSs

**How can I install a package in R and its addon packages ?**
Such that the following would work:

```
install.packages("TSA", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Without our having internet connection failutes?

I tried this:

```
Sys.setenv("ftp_proxy" = "1ncproxy1","ftp_proxy_user"="MyLoGiN","ftp_proxy_password"="MyPaSs")#Port = 80
```

ButI get :

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/src/contrib
# or 
cannot open: HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authentication Required'
```

Many thanks,

Comment: What is your operating system ? Why do you use ftp_proxy and not http_proxy ?

Comment: Windows7, my problem is to install packages from internet, I set the --internet2 option but still don't know how to mix authentication + package installation

Answer (score 3):

You are probably on Windows, so I would advice you to check the 'R on Windows FAQ' that came with your installation, particularly [**Question 2.19: The Internet download functions fail**](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#The-Internet-download-functions-fail_002e).  You may need to restart R with the `--internet2` option (IIRC) for the proxy settings to come into effect.

I always found this very cumbersome.  An alternative is to install a proxy-aware webdownloader as eg `wget` (as a windows binary) where you set the proxy options in a file in your home directory.  This is all from memory, I think the last time I was faced with such a proxy was in 2005 so YMMV.

Comment: I spent some time on the FAQ and particularly on the 2.19, I didn't solve the problem :-/

Comment: Try a two-step. Solve `download.file()` first, then install from a local file.

Answer (score 3):

As @juba states, I think you want to set the http_proxy. From `?download.file`:

> Usernames and passwords can be set for HTTP proxy transfers via
>   environment variable http_proxy_user in the form user:passwd.
>   Alternatively, http_proxy can be of the form
>   "http://user:pass@proxy.dom.com:8080/"

So, try: `Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://MyLoGiN:MyPaSs@1ncproxy1:80")`

Be aware though:

> These environment variables must be set before the download code is
>   first used: they cannot be altered later by calling Sys.setenv.

So you are best off calling it in your `.Rprofile`

Comment: Hmm, have you tried using the IP address of the proxy instead of its name?

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Juba, above. This worked for me:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://username:password@the-proxy.mycompany.com:80
$ R
> install.packages("quantmod")
```

Comment: i found that this did not work for me on linux unless I set method="wget" in install.packages

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install swirl package, and had the same problem - proxy with authorisation.

After some experiments i found decision.
May be my answer will help for anybody.
On Windows 7 :

1. set 1 or more (if ou need)  env variables  http_proxy (https_proxy and ftp_proxy if you need) (If you don`t know how  - read there http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm )
   It`s look like that 
   [env variables for proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fzzb.jpg)
2. format http_proxy="http://Proxyusername:ProxyUserPassw@proxyServName:ProxyPort"
3. Use '**@**' instead of %40
4. In RStudio **Tools->Global Options->Packages** release check box "Use Internet Explorer library /proxy for HTTP"

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff Taylor wrote, R can indirectly make use of a proxy server. You need to specify the proxy server for both, http and https protocols, as follows:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://user:pass@proxy_server:port
$ export https_proxy=http://user:pass@proxy_server:port
$ R
> install.packages("<package_name>")
```

I just tested this solution and it works like a charm. The answer from Jeff was correct but unfortunatelly for most cases incomplete, as most of the servers are nowadays accesible over https.