# Require users to register when installing R package

Tags: r, install.packages

Is it possible to require users to register when installing a R package (I produced with a friend)?
I'd like to be able to do this so we can keep stats on how many people have downloaded the package, where they're from and ask them to agree to reference the peer-reviewed article which refers to this package.

Comment: You can hide your package on some private server that requires authentication before download but that makes it difficult for users to install because they won't be able to do it in R. And once they download it, they can redistribute it. R embodies the open source spirit so it doesn't make it easy to require registration. You could show a startup message when the package loads, but you can't really enforce anything.

Comment: In that spirit, *"ask them to agree to reference the peer-reviewed article"* should be handled by the `CITATION` file in the package, at least in theory, ref: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#CITATION-files. Agreed, private server requiring free registration will give you initial downloads, but I admit to being skeptical of packages that require registration to download. (Obviously, proof-of-concept vignettes/papers/publications and such are required to convince me it's worth pursuing.)

Comment: To see stats there are a couple of options. To track simple stats, there are packages like cranlogs. I suppose one could ping a webservice with basic data user data in the .onLoad function but I doubt anyone would be happy about you doing that (privacy!).

Comment: Is it possible to make people really dislike your package and not want to use it? Absolutely.

Comment: I remember a geospatial related package asking for a response to a licensing question after calling it with library(). Maybe they could use the same mechanism. I don't recall which package it was! data.table also uses startupmessages to market their datacamp course

Comment: as @BrandonBertelsen, I think you'd be best using the start up message to try and advertise that you have a survey requesting this information. You don't want to force this on users of your package as it would turn people away.

Comment: I'm okay with random ads (e.g., `ggplot2`), as long as they are suppressble (i.e., done using `packageStartupMessage`). If they are done with something less-suppressible, I raise an issue and will consider submitting a PR. If it starts making arbitrary network connections without clear indication and transparent intent, I'll be quick to kill R, investigate, and probably uninstall the package. I might be a bit paranoid in this, but that doesn't mean we'll never see a virus or malware in R packages.

Comment: Untested but possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14524449/3358272. With those suggestions, it sounds like you could have a setup using a proxy-like interface where only people you authenticate are allowed to install the package ... and then they can use `install.packages`. I don't lightly counter @MrFlick's comment, but perhaps you can test and report back.

Comment: One side-effect of this is that you will not be able to advertise/publish it on CRAN. This is not a death-sentence, but will likely reduce its consumption. Also, using the proxy (from my previous comment) will likely preclude many corporate users who are unable to change proxy settings and/or are required to use a company CRAN mirror. Just thoughts, good luck.